# If the limit comparison test fails

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Just want to make sure I'm applying the limit comparison test correctly. And if so and it does indeed fail, what should be my next step in determining if the series diverges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5n^3 + 7n^2 + 9}{n^6+2n^3+1}$$
Taking the dominant terms this reduces to $\frac{1}{n^3}$ which converges.
$$\frac{5n^3 + 7n^2 + 9}{n^6+2n^3+1} * \frac{n^3}{1}$$
$$= \frac{5n^6 + 7n^5 + 9n^3}{n^6+2n^3+1}$$
$$= \frac{5 + 7n^5 + 9}{2+1}$$
$$= \frac{7n^5 + 14}{3}$$
$\frac{7n^5 + 14}{3}$ isn't finite for $n=\infty$, so the test fails. Where should I go from here?

Comment: There is an error between the second and third lines. Wrong calculation.

Answer (score 1):

After this
$$ \frac{5n^6 + 7n^5 + 9n^3}{n^6+2n^3+1}$$
you made errors.

The limit above is finite and it's values is $5$

Indeed
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n^6 + 7n^5 + 9n^3}{n^6+2n^3+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^6\left(5+\frac{7}{n}+\frac{9}{n^3}\right)}{n^6\left(1+\frac{2}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^6}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5+\frac{7}{n}+\frac{9}{n^3}}{1+\frac{2}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^6}}=5$$